# SuiteCRM Module Loader -mkdir permisions denied

Tags: linux, apache, sugarcrm, bitnami, suitecrm

I'm trying to upgrade the module of Security groups but in the process throw me one error on the browser!,

`Including: cache/upgrades/temp/6wux90/scripts/pre_install.php
17% success....`

**Display Log

> ```
> Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied occurred in** 
> /opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs/include/utils/sugar_file_utils.php on line 74 [2017-06-09 08:24:29] display_stack_trace caller, file: 
> /opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs/include/utils.php line#: 3439
> [L:](:StackTraceErrorHandler)
> /opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs/include/utils/sugar_file_utils.php[L:74](:mkdir)
> /opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs/include/dir_inc.php[L:119](:sugar_mkdir)
> /opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs/ModuleInstall/ModuleInstaller.php[L:2024](:mkdir_recursive)
> /opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs/ModuleInstall/ModuleInstaller.php[L:2062]
> (ModuleInstaller:copy_recursive_with_backup)
> /opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs/ModuleInstall/ModuleInstaller.php[L:1257](ModuleInstaller:copy_recursive_with_backup)
> /opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs/ModuleInstall/ModuleInstaller.php[L:295](ModuleInstaller:copy_path)
> /opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs/ModuleInstall/ModuleInstaller.php[L:170](ModuleInstaller:install_copy)    
> /opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs/modules/Administration/UpgradeWizard_commit.php[L:343](ModuleInstaller:install)
> /opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs/include/MVC/View/SugarView.php[L:761](:include_once)
> /opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs/include/MVC/View/views/view.classic.php[L:74](SugarView:includeClassicFile)
> /opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs/include/MVC/View/SugarView.php[L:169](ViewClassic:display)
> /opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs/include/MVC/Controller/SugarController.php[L:363](SugarView:process)
> /opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs/include/MVC/Controller/SugarController.php[L:310](SugarController:processView)
> /opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs/include/MVC/SugarApplication.php[L:105](SugarController:execute)
> /opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs/index.php[L:52](SugarApplication:execute)
> ```
>
> `**Warning: copy(** ec7a-upload/upgrades/module/6.5.24_SecuritySuite_Full-Edition_v2.9.5-restore/modules/SecurityGroups/SecurityGroup.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory occurred in /opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs/ModuleInstall/ModuleInstaller.php on line 2027 [2017-06-09 08:24:29] display_stack_trace caller, file: /opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs/include/utils.php line#: 3439`

:

Screenshot here:
[image: Step 1]

The permissions I'm using are:

```
# sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .
# sudo chmod -R 755 .
# sudo chmod -R 775 cache custom modules themes data upload config_override.php
```

And into the `config.php` file:

```
'default_permissions' =>  
   array (
   'dir_mode' => 1528,
    /*'file_mode' => 432,*/
    'file_mode' => 493,
    'user' => '',
    'group' => '',
  ),
```

What's happening?? please help!

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here.

Could you please execute this commands in order to set write permissions in the directories in the suitecrm installation?

sudo find /opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs/ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo find /opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;

This will set write permissions for folders and files.

Also, could you please execute this?

ls -la /opt/bitnami/apps/suitecrm/htdocs/include/utils

Best regards.

Note: This case is a duplicate of https://community.bitnami.com/t/module-loader-mkdir-permisions-denied/49815/2